# How to Use HTTP Receive GET Message in Orchestration?

Tags: get, biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

I have set up a HTTP Receive (req-response) adapter and the message appears to be getting to the message box. When I create an orchestration using a direct bound logical port, I am getting the message but everything I have tried to read the message body has failed (using passthrough pipeline, XML pipeline with allow unrecognized files = true) but I get exceptions any time I try to use the incoming message (message assignments, [sending the message to a custom module to try to read the part(s)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/how-to-use-expressions-to-perform-message-assignments#retrieving-message-parts)).

Rather than go into details on exceptions, can anyone point to instructions on what the proper way to access/use the body of the HTTP [Get messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee267547(v=bts.10).aspx) within an orchestration? To explain what I am trying to do, I want to take the query string (body) and send it verbatim to another orchestration for processing, so I simply want to extract the body (query string) from the message.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: I think the issue is BizTalk can't interpret the message. Have you tried a flat-file schema and receive pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a GET request without a body you need to use the WCF-WebHttp adapter rather than the deprecated BTSHTTPReceive.dll

With the WCF-WebHttp you can use the Variable Mapping to populate message context properties with the URI parameters.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try this method first but it appeared it required me to explicitly write in the allowed operations/query string. What I'm trying to do is allow users to go to something like mysite.com/ and collect anything after the slash (/). Is that possible?   https://imgur.com/No3HTU0

Comment: Also, how would you access the Brand, OrderID, OrderNO properties from within the orchestration? All the walk throughs I can find is getting the message into the msgbox/orchestration (which I can do just fine) but what type should the receive shape be? XMLDocument, the schema I set in the Variable mapping, Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Any, etc?

Comment: @bee The same as you would any message context property.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was to NOT use the HTTP adapter for GET requests. I did not realize the HTTP adapter has effectively been deprecated. For basic GET requests I had to switch to the [WCF-WebHTTP adapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj572859.aspx) and make sure to include the property in the property schema and then make sure to set the schema in the variable mapping as the property schema, not the message type schema of the incoming message. I wish the Microsoft documentation was more clear that the HTTP adapter cannot be used for very basic GET requests in which a body is not provided in the request.